# Pygame Gravity Script

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a python script with pygame to simulate gravity. The problem is, my "player" keeps getting stuck at the bottom without bouncing even once. I'm using python 3.4.1 if that helps. Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

disp_w = 800
disp_h = 600
disp = pygame.display.set_mode((disp_w,disp_h))

pygame.display.set_caption('Gravity')

player_x = disp_w/2
player_y = 0
player = pygame.image.load('images/player.png')

gravity = 0.1
speed = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    player_y += speed
    speed += gravity

    if player_y > disp_h:
        speed = speed * -0.7

    disp.fill((0,0,0))
    disp.blit(player,(player_x,player_y))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: Gravity seems to be working as you would expect. If you would like the "player" to bounce when she hits the bottom, you'll need to model conservation of energy and the player being somewhere between completely elastic (i.e. releasing the collision energy through a rebound) and completely plastic (i.e. completely absorbing the collision energy).

Comment: @Simon I reckon the `speed = speed * -0.7` is an attempt to model the bouncing.

Comment: @irrelephant: Ah yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one frame, you'll fall beneath the floor by, say, 1.0 unit. Your speed then goes to -0.7.

On the next frame, therefore, you end up below the floor by 0.3 units and flip your speed again, to +0.49.

On the following frame, you're below the floor by 0.79 units and flip the sign again, and so on. You never get out.

Try:

```
if player_y > disp_h:
    # stop the player at the floor
    player_y = disp_h
    speed = speed * -0.7
```

Comment: Also, if the player is intended to stay above the bottom, the test should perhaps be something like `if player_y+player.get_height() > disp_h: player_y = disp_h-player.get_height()`, given that `player_y` is the top of the player image.