# Player does not stop at bottom edge of screen when using gravity in pygame tutorial

Tags: python, pygame, gravity

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://opensource.com/article/19/11/simulate-gravity-python to allow my sprite to go to the bottom edge of the screen and nothing more. But following the tutorial code to the point where it says:

*... Make your gravity function look like this:*

```
def gravity(self):
    self.movey += 3.2  # how fast player falls

    if self.rect.y > worldy and self.movey >= 0:
        self.movey = 0
        self.rect.y = worldy-ty
```

**even though the player doesn't stop at the bottom edge of the screen when using gravity.**
I tried to add one more `ty` as suggested in the tutorial where it says

*... An easy fix is to make your player sprite bounce higher by adding another -ty to its new Y position after it hits the bottom of the game world:*

```
def gravity(self):
    self.movey += 3.2  # how fast player falls

    if self.rect.y > worldy and self.movey >= 0:
        self.movey = 0
        self.rect.y = worldy-ty-ty
```

**so that my code looks like this:**

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
'''
Objects
'''

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn an enemy
    '''

    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', img))
        #self.image.convert_alpha()
        #self.image.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.counter = 0

    def move(self):
        '''
        enemy movement
        '''
        distance = 20
        speed = 8

        if self.counter >= 0 and self.counter <= distance:
            self.rect.x += speed
        elif self.counter >= distance and self.counter <= distance * 2:
            self.rect.x -= speed
        else:
            self.counter = 0

        self.counter += 1


class Level:

    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()  # create enemy group

    def bad_1(self, lvl, eloc):
        if lvl == 1:
            enemy = Enemy(eloc[0],eloc[1],'yeti.png') # spawn enemy
            self.enemy_list.add(enemy)              # add enemy to group
        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )

        return self.enemy_list

    def bad_2(self, lvl, eloc):
        if lvl == 1:
            enemy = Enemy(eloc[0],eloc[1],'spr.png') # spawn enemy
            self.enemy_list.add(enemy)              # add enemy to group
        if lvl == 2:
            print("Level " + str(lvl) )

        return self.enemy_list

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn a player
    '''
    def gravity(self):
        self.movey += 3.2 # how fast player falls

        if self.rect.y > worldy and self.movey >= 0:
            self.movey = 0
            self.rect.y = worldy-ty-ty-ty-ty-ty-ty
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.health = 10
        self.frame = 0
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            img = pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join('images', 'hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
            self.images.append(img)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def control(self, x, y):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame // ani]
        # collisions
        enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy_list, False)
        for enemy in enemy_hit_list:
            self.health -= 1
            print(self.health)

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 * ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[(self.frame // ani)]


'''
Setup
'''

worldx = 560
worldy = 420

fps = 40  # frame rate
ani = 4  # animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
main = True

BLUE = (25, 25, 200)
BLACK = (23, 23, 23)
WHITE = (254, 254, 254)
ALPHA = (0, 255, 0)

world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'stage.png')).convert()
backdropbox = world.get_rect()
player = Player()  # spawn player
player.rect.x = 0
player.rect.y = 0
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10  # how fast to move
l = Level()
eloc = [200,20]
enemy_list = l.bad_1(1, eloc)
eloc = [100,10]
enemy_list = l.bad_2(1, eloc)

'''
Main loop
'''
while main == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(-steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('jump')

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(-steps, 0)
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

#    world.fill(BLACK)
    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
    player.gravity() # check gravity
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)  #refresh player position
    enemy_list.draw(world)
    for e in enemy_list:
        e.move()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

but the sprite doesn't stop at the bottom edge of the screen (again) and I get the following error when the code breaks by itself on execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 188, in <module>
    player.gravity() # check gravity
  File "game.py", line 72, in gravity
    self.rect.y = worldy-ty-ty-ty-ty-ty-ty
NameError: name 'ty' is not defined
```

**If I try to decrease or increase (depending on how much bigger or smaller) the screen size where it says:**

```
worldx = 560
worldy = 420
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 188, in <module>
    player.gravity() # check gravity
  File "game.py", line 72, in gravity
    self.rect.y = worldy-ty
NameError: name 'ty' is not defined
```

I have encountered this question [Pygame Gravity Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750777/pygame-gravity-script) but comparing I could not understand where the code failure arises.

The original images are from here https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/opp2_sprites.zip but I have separated in imgur for easy explanation:

**content folder images:**

**For enemy (sprit) is yeti.png:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXLko.jpg

**For background is stage.png:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmyok.jpg

and the image of the player:

**spr.png:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGsb3.jpg

Comment: where do you define `ty` ? If it is not global variable then it will not work. Or maybe it is `self.ty`, not `ty`.

Comment: @furas Thanks! I thought so too, but if you adjust the screen to certain dimensions `y` the code won't break even though the player doesn't stop at the bottom edge of the screen. That's how the code was presented at https://opensource.com/article/19/11/simulate-gravity-python. But I will try here to add the variables suggested by you, although I had ruled out this need or relationship to the problem.

Comment: BTW: maybe you should use `self.rect.y = worldy` or better `self.rect.bottom = worldy`. And you should compare also `bottom` - `if self.rect.bottom > worldy`

Comment: @furas I will try this change suggested by you

Comment: BTW: in link which you add you can see `ty = 64 #tile size` but you don't have it in your code. But if you use `rect.bottom` then you don't need `ty`

Comment: So I saw that it is set, this is true, maybe I have inadvertently deleted this snippet `ty = 64 #tile size`. But it turns out that previously, after noticing this player problem, I tried to copy the full code from https://opensource.com/article/19/11/simulate-gravity-python and tried to compile, and got the same problem. Even now with your note I copied the respective code again and it didn't work

Comment: maybe you have other problem - or author made mistake in original code. You can use `print(self.rect.y, worldy)` to check values in variable in `gravity()`

Comment: I run code and problem is that it check `if self.rect.y > worldy` but it should compare `if self.rect.y > worldy-ty` or `if self.rect.y+ty > worldy` or better using `bottom` - `if self.rect.bottom > worldy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In original code on https://opensource.com/article/19/11/simulate-gravity-python is

```
ty = 64 #tile size
```

but you don't have it in your code - and it gives your error.

But you could use `rect.bottom` and then you may not need `ty`

```
def gravity(self):
    self.movey += 3.2  # how fast player falls

    if self.rect.bottom > worldy and self.movey >= 0: # <-- uses bottom
        self.movey = 0
        self.rect.bottom = worldy # <-- uses bottom
```

---

**BTW:** If you will add plaforms to game then you can create platform at the bottom (below bottom border) and then it should stop player.

---

**BTW:** To stop on platform it would need

```
    # collisions
    enemy_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemy_list, False)
    for enemy in enemy_hit_list:
        self.health -= 1
        print(self.health)

    plat_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, plat_list, False)
    for p in plat_hit_list:
        #self.health -= 1
        #print(self.health)
        self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top

    ground_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, ground_list, False)
    for g in ground_hit_list:
        #self.health -= 1
        #print(self.health)
        self.rect.bottom = g.rect.top
```

It would be good also to reduce gravity speed because in very big speed it may jump below platform without checking collision with platform.

```
def gravity(self):
    self.movey += 3.2 # how fast player falls
    #print(self.rect.bottom, worldy)

    # reduce speed so it will not jump out platfrom
    if self.movey >= 15:
        self.movey = 6

    if self.rect.bottom > worldy and self.movey >= 0:
        self.movey = 0
        self.rect.bottom = worldy

    #print(self.rect.bottom, worldy)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try here for now

Comment: maybe there is next part of this tutorial because. I see some incomplete elements - I it doesn't stop on platform, etc.. I added some other changes.

Comment: @ThankXD I don't understand what's different about my folder where the game code is. Because I added self.rect.bottom = worldy and it resolved but the code I copied including `ty = 64 # tile size` had not resolved. I made a screenshot of the game running when it gives the error before adding `self.rect.bottom` see https://imgur.com/6BnHeaR and made a new screenshot using ` self.rect.bottom` see https://imgur.com/LhbuTjJ

Comment: I use `if self.rect.bottom > worldy` but original code use `if self.rect.y > worldy` and this also makes problem.

Comment: I added comments in `gravity()` - in two places you have to uses `bottom` or `world-ty`. Original code uses `world-ty` only in one place and it makes problem.

Comment: BTW: I sent a message to author with information about this problem.

Comment: about *maybe there is next part of this tutorial because ...*, see at the top of this address https://opensource.com/article/20/1/add-scorekeeping-your-python-game you can see the 10 tutorials in the series.